# GridGain/ Ignite query list data type

Tags: sql, ignite, gridgain, sqlline

I'm trying to figure out how to work with a list datatype in a Gridgain query, I have an object which has a field
`@QuerySqlField private final List<Integer> expertGroupIds;` that I can receive during selects but I can't manage to create an update query on the list, and can't find anywhere what is the correct syntax while working from the Gridgain sqlline client.

Also, what I'm finally trying to achieve is to have a select query that will find all objects where expertGroupIds has at least one element similar to a list receive as a parameter (basically I need to check if the 2 lists have any intersections)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't is the short answer. There's no way to filter (a WHERE clause) or update it from SQL.

But you can if you normalise it, as you would with a traditional relational database.